# Cannot use 'with' in a Eloquent Query Builder Macro

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I was attempting to use `with` on a Eloquent macro, but I get this error message:

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::with()
```

The following works:

```
$builder = Model::query();
$builder->with('relationship')->toSql();
```

But if I do this inside a macro:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder;

Builder::macro('foobar', function() {
    $this->with('relationship')->toSql());
});

$builder = Model::query();
$builder->foobar();
```

Then I get an error message.

Is this a bug or something that I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong import, try adding the macro to the eloquent builder instead:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
```